# Create Object Name with Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to create object name using arrays. How can I do it?

For example :

```
String dizi ={"person1","person2","person3"};
Person dizi[0] = new Person();
```

Comment: format your code (add 4 spaces before the code lines). I would edit it but I have 5 edits in the queue, so I can't

Comment: Sorry, not possible. Give the Person object a name parameter.

Comment: I think, first what you should do is that read something about OOP.  And little bit clarify your question.

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code. To name a few: `String dizi` defines a single string, not an array. `Person dizi[0]` redefines a variable (not possible in the same scope) and looks like an array declaration and element access at the same time. I guess you want `Person[] dizi = new Person[3]; dizi[0] = new Person("person1"); ...` instead.

Comment: the more important question would be, why would you like to do it in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the type of object stored in the array from String to Person. Instead, you will need two separate arrays, and supposing you have a Person(String) constructor, loop over first array to fill second array:

```
String[] names = {"person1","person2","person3"};
Person[] persons = new Person[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    persons[i] = new Person(names[i]);
```

Comment: from what i read in it he want, `person1` for example, to be the variable name, and not change what it refers to.

Comment: Seems like that indeed. Certainly cannot be done in Java.

Comment: Above code will work if you have a Person(String name) constructor, and will fill an array of Person objects. It will not create a "Person person1" variable if that was what you intended to do - this is not possible in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The technique you are trying to use works in some languages, especially interpreted ones. It uses the language symbol table as a map.

In Java, you can construct your own map:

```
Map<String,Person> myMap = new HashMap<String, Person>();
myMap.put(dizi[0], new Person());
```

and access it using:

```
myMap.get(dizi[0])
```

Comment: @ErenArıcı No, it is a Map, not a List.